# XML Transformer exclude param xml:base

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Using javax.xml.Transform includes xml:base attributes in a transformed xml file . Here is the scenario .

**Sample XML File :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE security [
<!ENTITY attachparam SYSTEM "attach-value.xml">
<!ENTITY udf SYSTEM "udfasset.xml">
]>
<property>
           &attachparam;

</property>
```

**attach-value.xml**

```
<value regex=".+">localhost</value>
<value regex="^[A-Z]+">allow</value>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no">
<property> 
     <value regex=".+" xml:base="file:///home/bharathi/attach-value.xml">localhost</value>    
     <value regex="^[A-Z]+" xml:base="file:///home/bharathi/attach-value.xml">allow</value>    
</property>
```

**Java Code:**

```
               TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

                String tempFile = "/home/bharathi/out.xml";
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "tempFile is :: " + tempFile);

                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(tempFile));

                transformer.transform(source, result);
```

How can i exclude xml:base attribute when transform?

Comment: I don't know where the xml:base is coming from, and the first step is to find out. Does it appear in the DOM that you use as input to the transformation, or is it added by the XSLT engine?